# How to install Black Duck Detect manually in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Currently, my ci Jenkins version is 2.41.

Due to restarting of Jenkins my Black Duck detect version got upgraded to the 
latest version 1.5.0 due to which Jenkins is throwing errors.
You can see the image below:

[Please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtNzQ.png)

But I want to revert the changes to an older version of Black Duck Detect i.e 1.0.2.

Due to some obvious reasons, I cannot **restart or upgrade** my Jenkins again and again.

After going through some of the earlier posts, I got a solution which stated:
You need to download the older version of Black Duck hub plugin in **.hpi** format and place it in your **plugins** folder manually and then manually restart your Jenkins which would fix your problem.

But, after trying this solution also my problem was not solved. It didn't display any option in the build section of Jenkins, displaying any build option for selecting **Black Duck Detect** even when Black Duck Hub 2.1.1 is already installed for connection settings.

Any help regarding this particular issue would be really appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the contents of `/tools/Detect_Installation` folder.
In that folder, the plugin keeps all downloaded versions. Also try placing the plugin jar version (1.0.2) in that folder manually in case it is not downloaded automatically next time you execute a job using detect plugin.